# Add triangle before submenu using css

Tags: jquery, html, css

How can i add triangle to the following example [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wPWDm/6/)

I need to remove the parent menu with white background and  show triangle   to to make it look more like this

[image]

I tried to add following css but it i snot working

```
.dropdown li:first-child > a:after {
{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: -5px;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #0A8F36;
    opacity:0.6;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}
```

UPDATE:

I managed to make it work to some extend but still have some design issue, any help is appreciated

Latest Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wPWDm/17/

Comment: [Pure CSS Speech Bubbles](http://www.sitepoint.com/pure-css3-speech-bubbles/). It's not exactly what you want but it's a good start

Comment: http://cssarrowplease.com/ is quite useful

Comment: Add display:block to your CSS above.

Comment: I did earlier, it didn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hope this helps, I have commented out some of your css and jquery scripts. Also, added a style at the end please kindly refer this link **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yuvaraj_b/wPWDm/21/)**

The css I added follows,

```
.dropdown ul li:first-child > a:after {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 left: 30px;
 top: -8px;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-left: 5px solid transparent;
 border-right: 5px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 8px solid #028F41;
 }
```

Comment: Will check and modify it buddy!!

Comment: Hey buddy tell me whether this helps,[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yuvaraj_b/wPWDm/19/)

Comment: I will edit my answer with this new link then buddy!! You are welcome. If you are satisfied with my solution please rate me :)

Comment: It look fine to me except for the `Menu Four` triangle show at left side can you change it your updated solution so that it come on right side for menus which show contents on left side of menu... Appreciate your help.. Bala Bala praji..

Comment: Hey Buddy I'm not a professtional designer but I managed to bring the things to right side. Hope this helps. **[New Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yuvaraj_b/wPWDm/21/)**

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply a class to the list items that have dropdown divs and then you can apply the pseudo element to that.

[**Codepen Example**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/buADl)

Comment: Sorry was correcting my example. This one detects, using jQuery's .has, whether an li has a ul inside and applies a class. It then ripples adding additional classes as required.

Comment: It's easily adaptable with a little work. We can't do it all for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried something  by adding extra `.arrow_div`  ans apply css to it, check menuone you will see black arrow, may be this you looking for, better suggestion have a background image which have arrow and set it as you menudiv background

**[SAMPLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wPWDm/12/)**