# What is the Name of the 'cursor' in this sub menu?

Tags: css

I'm sorry this is not a programming question.

Just a simple question. I want to know what is the name in the black circle (for submenu). I want to create like that.

Thanks.[image]

Comment: You'd like to create an [arrow/triangle in CSS](http://cssarrowplease.com/)?

Comment: @oGeez thank you so much. Awesome tool. Case closed!

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with css (and it is not a cursor). Check this answers here in SO: [Add triangle before submenu using css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19135896/add-triangle-before-submenu-using-css)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.triangle {
content: "";
display: block;
width: 0;
height: 0;
border: inset 25px;
border-color: white transparent transparent transparent;
border-top-style: solid;
}
```